# Database per Tenant: Every tenant has a separate, dedicated database to store the data related to that tenant

Tags: asp.net-core, multi-tenant, abp

I was trying to implement Multitenancy architecture using ABP Framework, but somehow unable to find any solution in the given samples code where they implemented each tenant has a separate, dedicated database to store the data related to that tenant. Please let me know anyone tried this implementation using ABP Framework. If possible provide a GitHub link for code reference.

Comment: Welcome! Please note that questions asking for offsite resource recommendations are off-topic. Also, it's unclear what, exactly, you're having a problem with, as you've shown no code, errors, etc. And you haven't defined what "ABP Framework" is (no definition in your question, and no related tag). Please be sure to edit your question to contain all needed information. However, if this is just a recommendation request, this would be off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

you need to enter the tenant's connection string to the database table `AbpTenantConnectionStrings`